# "facebook cannot be resolved or is not a field " error in getting facebook userid

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

here i am trying to get the id of user login with facebook details in to my app
and in the following code i am getting "facebook can not be resolved or not a field error

```
 try {
    // PROFILE DETAILS AND FRIENDS COUNTER    
    String queryUserInfo = "SELECT uid FROM user WHERE uid = me()";
    Bundle paramUserInfo = new Bundle();
    paramUserInfo.putString("method", "fql.query");
    paramUserInfo.putString("query", queryUserInfo);
    String responseUserInfo = Util.facebook.request(paramUserInfo);
//"facebook cannot be resolved or is not a field " error in getting facebook userid.
       JSONArray JAUserData = new JSONArray(responseUserInfo);
       for (int i = 0; i < JAUserData.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject JOUserData = JAUserData.getJSONObject(i);
            if (JOUserData.has("uid")) {
            String getUserID = JOUserData.getString("uid");
            }
       }
     } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
```

Comment: Add your Util class and the place where you're initializing your facebook object so we can see what's happening.

Comment: i think `facebook` right here. so, when you add `method, fql.query`, what you try to do? in this case, you need to add a sub-path `/fql` and then use query. like this: `https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=YOURQUERY`

Answer (score -1):

Don't like fql, but i think this:

1. you can't add parameter `method` as `fql-query`
2. you must add subpath  `/fql`
3. you must NOT USE fql for such simple things (`https://graph.facebook.com/me` will help)

After all:

You need to create a request with subpath `/fql` and with only one parameter: `q=YOURQUERY`

Example: `https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=YOUREQUEST&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN`

Advise: use `Graph-API` instead, it is very simple.

How to begin: [It is Graph Api](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/)

And you can find [Tools for facebook Api](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/) (i recommend `Graph API Explorer`)

Comment: i am using graph api , in that how can i get the user id? who are log in with facebook details in to my app..

Comment: as i said, just use `https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN` <- this query will help

Comment: @loldop Your answer has nothing to do with the error in the question.